# Main character is reincarnated into an abandoned prince with a system

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character (who had brown hair) is reincarnated into an abandoned prince with a system which gives him overpowered subordinates. The first was a nine tailed fox and then a Buddha and after that later two devils.

The main character also got a dragon girl as his subordinate later on and I think he later on conquered many kingdoms and obtained an army from the system.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: About half ayear ago

Comment: I think on Mangageko.com, or Manwhahauas

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the main character?

Comment: full colour and I think the main character had brown hair

Comment: the main charactor also got a dragon girl as his subordinate later on and I think he later on quonquered many kingdoms and obtained an army from the system

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Please help me I need the name

Answer (score 4):

I found the manga myself but thank you to both of you which provided assistance.
The manga is [Shenwu Tianzun](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/zarylkm/shenwu-tianzun):

> I was once the Supreme God of Physique, standing tall above others. However, I was betrayed by those whom I thought of as my most trustworthy friends. They had schemed against me in an attempt to kill me, which was almost successful. Fortunately, a fraction of my soul had managed to escape into the body of a seriously injured child giving me another chance at life, and revenge.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until the question is 48 hours old before the site will let you do that.